# How to replace every row that are filled with zero with a certain value from a Pytorch tensor?

Tags: python, pytorch, vectorization, tensor

I have a Pytorch tensor of the size `bsize x 50 x 50` where some of the rows are completely filled with zeros:

```py
         [[0, 2, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
         [2, 0, 2,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 2, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
         ...,
         [0, 0, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0]],

        [[0, 2, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
         [2, 0, 2,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 2, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
```

I want to  replace the rows filled with zeros with a negative value `-100` throughout in the tensor.
Expected tensor -

```py
         [[0, 2, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
         [2, 0, 2,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 2, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
         ...,
         [-100, -100, -100,  ..., -100,-100, -100],
         [-100, -100, -100,  ..., -100,-100, -100],
         [-100, -100, -100,  ..., -100,-100, -100]],

        [[0, 2, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
         [2, 0, 2,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 2, 0,  ..., 0, 0, 0],
```

Whats the best way to do this avoiding a loop over the row shape ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `x` is your tensor with `BxRxC` (batch, rows, and columns), you can do something like this:

```py
x[(x == 0).all(dim=-1)] = -100
```

Basically:

- `x == 0` returns a boolean tensor (shape `BxRxC`) with `True` where it is equal to zero;
- then, `.all(dim=-1)` returns another boolean tensor, now with shape `BxR` because we chose to do `all` in the last dimension (`-1`), with `True` where **all** the columns are `True`;
- finally, we use this boolean tensor to index the original tensor and the `-100` is assigned to the `True` positions.

Comment: Oh I see, there is a dimension arg on the `all` func. I did not know about that. Let me try this and quickly mark it correct.

Comment: Works perfectly fine ! Thanks a ton for making me avoid the nasty loops on tensor obj